# Appending to a Python global list of dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

See code snippet

```
global_list = [{}] # list of dictionaries
new_dict = {x:2, y:1}

new_dict[x] = 5
new_dict[y] = 4

global_list.append(new_dict)  # appending x:5, y:4

new_dict[x] = 2
new_dict[y] = 3          # appending x:2, y:3

print (global_list)
```

I expected the global_list output to be [{x:5, y:4}, {x:2, y:3}]
But all elements are overwritten by the last appended element. The output is
[{x:2, y:3}, {x:2, y:3}]

How do i fix the overwrite issue?

Comment: Your code doesn't match your claimed results - the first dict in your list should be empty.  But I think the point you're missing is that `.append()` doesn't make a copy of anything - changing the dict after the append is no different than changing it before.

Comment: plus, Before asking questions make sure that your code runs without typos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `.copy()` on your dictionary when you are appending it to the list. Because you are adding the dictionary object into your list, when you modify it after it will also modify it in your list

If I use `.copy`:

```py
global_list = []
new_dict = {'x':2, 'y':1}

new_dict['x'] = 5
new_dict['y'] = 4

global_list.append(new_dict.copy())

new_dict['x'] = 2
new_dict['y'] = 3

global_list.append(new_dict.copy())
```

And you print it you will get:

```py
>>> global_list
[{'x': 5, 'y': 4}, {'x': 2, 'y': 3}]
```